# Prove equality for every positive integer by induction

Tags: induction

The task is to prove this equation by induction:
$$\left(1-\frac {1}{n^2}\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{(n+1)^2}\right)...\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n-1)^2}\right)=1 - \frac {1}{2n-1}$$
I've done the base case, but I got stuck here:
$$\left(1-\frac {1}{(n+1)^2}\right)...\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)=\left(1-\frac {1}{2n-1}\right)
\left(\frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{n^2}}\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$
What should be done now?

Any help appreaciated.

Comment: The difference of two squares can be factored

Comment: @Empy2 I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to help. Which squares do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that
$$A = \left(1-\frac {1}{n^2}\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{(n+1)^2}\right) \ldots \left(1-\frac {1}{(2n-1)^2}\right)=1 - \frac {1}{2n-1}$$ holds for some $n \in \mathbb N$. We shall show it for $n+1$:
$$\left(1-\frac {1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac {1}{(n+2)^2}\right) \ldots \left(1-\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}\right) = A \cdot \frac{\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n)^2}\right) \cdot \left(1-\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac {1}{n^2}\right)}$$ $$= \left(1 - \frac {1}{2n-1} \right ) \cdot \frac{\left(1-\frac {1}{(2n)^2}\right) \cdot \left(1-\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac {1}{n^2}\right)} = \frac{2n-2}{2n-1} \cdot \frac{\frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)}{4n^2} \cdot \frac{(2n)(2n+2)}{(2n+1)^2}}{\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n^2}} $$ $$= \frac{2n}{2n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ after some cancelation. So, we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much!